# Append configuration to AWS EMR hadoop on bootstrap - not override

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, configuration, amazon-emr

In this documentation:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-plan-bootstrap.html

It says how to change a value in a key-value pair, in hadoop configuration files.

What I need is to **append** to a given value in a key-value pair - at the beginning of this value's text (such as classpath).

How can I do that?

Comment: At this point in time (2015-12-04), append is not possible. The approach would be to capture the classpath from a baseline cluster then write the entire new classpath in the configuration for later clusters.  The feedback is heard, though, by EMR product team.

Comment: Thank you. The reason that we need that is that the machines (ami 3.5 and up is what we have tested) are coming with some default jars that are different in their versions from the ones in our project. 
This causes an IncompatibleClassChangeError (and equivalents) and therefore we cannot run our jars. Examples for conflicting jars: jscience, gt-opengis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Christopher's answer (that this is currently impossible but might be possible in the future), here's what we did in the meantime -
copied the bootstrap script of configure-hadoop (s3://elasticmapreduce/bootstrap-actions/configure-hadoop) and added an append option.